# I am unable to understand the execution of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

my code:

```
<head>
     <!-- All the required scripts and CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.1.14.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Bootstrap nav-tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="mainTabs">
        <li class="active" ><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#group" data-toggle="tab" >Groups</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Content of nav-tabs -->    
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
            home
        </div>

        <div class=" fade tab-pane" id="group" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <h4>Groups</h4>
                        <button onclick="f5()"> Add Group</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Model -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" >Add New Group</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add" >Add</button> 
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <script type="text/javascript">         

    function f5() { 
        $('#myModal2').modal('show');
        $('#myModal2').on('click','#add', function (e) {
            console.log("new clicked");
            $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
        });
    }

    </script>

</body>
```

Now the problem is:
 
when I click on model button with id "add" first time then:

> Output: new clicked (printed one time)

when I click on model button with id "add" again:

> Now, Output: new clicked (printed two times)

when I click on model button with id "add" again:

> Now, Output: new clicked (printed three times)

when I click on model button with id "add" again:

> Now, Output: new clicked (printed four times)

Why it is happening?? I have searched on stack overflow and google but can't find anything useful to me. I am new to bootstrap, what I want is that each time that button with id "add" is clicked "new clicked" should be printed one time only.

Comment: every time `f5` runs, it's adding _another_ `click` handler to `#add`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe : So is there a way to not to do so... I am new to all this stuff...

Comment: Yes, but first you need to properly define the behaviour you actually want on the page - EG right now an extra button with the text `Add` is injected into the page.  It's not until you click that for the first time that the click handler for the original `Add` button (the one with the ID `add`) is added.  Clicking it again will add more event handlers, then clicking on the original add button will invoke those handlers.  The intent of your page is unclear - it needs to be more clearly defined.  Perhaps with a [lot less HTML clouding the question also](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code that attaches the event handler, including the event handler code itself. Also, what is "Output," the browser console? Which browser are you using?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: I have  posted the whole code inside the script tag there is JavaScript code with full HTML code and yes the output is on the firefox browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to check the .off method form jQuery.
It seems that you´re adding multiple listeners for the same thing, and you may want to remove all of them, before reassigning to avoid multiple prints of the same message.

For instance, in your f5 function (please, from now on use clear function for code clarity purposes) you´re creating a new listener for the same element, each time you execute it.
.off() will help you because before attaching a new event listeners, it will remove the previously added ones.

BUT, in order to do things in the right way, you should group you event listeners attach code in a single method like "addEventListeners()", and run that function once. (If you´re adding elements to a page after loading it, then use event delegation).

```
function f5() { 
    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
    $('#myModal2').off('click'); // will remove any previous listeners attached with on
    $('#myModal2').on('click','#add', function (e) {
        console.log("new clicked");
        $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
    });
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!! But i want to know more about the "addEventListeners()" and (If you´re adding elements to a page after loading it, then use event delegation) stuffs in details so if you provide some links to them it will be very useful.

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/on/, it contains a lot of info that will help you. Glad it helped.

Comment: ´function addEventListeners() {
  //all your event listeners code here...
}